# Enumerable class missing XML Documentation Comments in .net 4.6 project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xml-documentation, .net-4.6

I'm having this problem only when I target .Net 4.6 framework under both Visual Studio 2015 or 2013. There is no `XML Documentation Comments` present in the `Enumerable class` (System.Linq.Enumerable, \Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Core.dll). Anyone having the same problem?

---

I reinstalled .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx) but that didn't solve the problem. It seems that System.Core.xml file in \ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\ is missing some of the documentation. In the end I have used System.Core.xml file from .Net 4.5.2, and now documentation is visible.

Comment: I don't think this is a version problem. I think you just need to include that manually.

Comment: I have the same problem with other classes as well, e.g. Task. When I target v4.5, XML documentation is visible.

Comment: I have this exact same problem. Targeting .NET 4.6 will remove all XML documentation for anything in `mscorlib.dll`. I switch between .NET 4.5.2 and it all shows up again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it looks like they fixed this bug with the Update-1 for Visual Studio 2015. After installing update documentation is present!